# Liquibase pretending there's no liquibase.properties in the folder?

Tags: liquibase

I thought liquibase is looking for that file in the liquibases' folder I placed in my linux' /opt folder.

That folder (/opt/liquibase) is in profile.d already so I can call liquibase anywhere.

And yet, when I type "liquibase update", it gives the following output on the terminal:

```
Starting Liquibase at Sun, 15 Sep 2019 23:00:43 CEST (version 3.8.0 built at 2019-08-15T20:38:06Z)
Liquibase Community 3.8.0 by Datical
Errors:
The option --url is required.
The option --changeLogFile is required.
```

It makes me wonder why url and changeLogFile are missing, because in /opt/liquibase/liquibase.properties, I got the following lines:

```
driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/luquibase?autoReconnect=true&amp;useSSL=false
username: zend
password: zend
changeLogFile: ~/html/zend/sql/changelog.xml
```

What do I do wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is as-designed behavior. It is expected that people using liquibase will use it on multiple projects, so it looks for the `liquibase.properties` file in the current directory, which may not be the directory where the liquibase shell script lives.

Comment: Thank you, my friend! Seems I misunderstood the tutorial.

Comment: Glad I could help. I'll also make sure that the tutorial is more clear! Do you remember what tutorial you were following?

Comment: In [this tutorial](https://www.liquibase.org/quickstart.html), under Step 4, it says "Create a liquibase.properties. Add the following content to the file and save it in the directory that you extracted the Liquibase *.zip or *.tar.gz."

Comment: Thanks! I'll get that fixed.

Comment: I've updated the tutorial. Hopefully it makes more sense now. I really appreciate the feedback!